# How to put the 'next' link inside qtip2 tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip2

I'm trying to use qtip2 to create a tutorial with tooltips on my website.
What i want to do is this:

- have the "next" link somewhere inside the tooltips (instead of having the link only at the bottom)

I've set up a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrisscript/DY9n2/1). And i used this:

`... content: 'Description...' + ' <a id="next" href="#">Next &raquo;</a>'`

But my try didn't seem to work.

If you click on the "next" link at the bottom it works fine, **but the link inside the tooltip doesn't work**.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `delegate` , (depend on you jQuery version , you can also use the `on` instead of the `delegate`)

```
$(document).delegate("#next, #prev", "click", function (event) {
```

instead of

```
$('#next, #prev').bind('click', function(event) {
```

Here a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8yGL/)

Explanation :

I guess that the tooltip being added to the HTML DOM tree on a later stage - after the binding that is being done (`.bind`) , That's why the `delegate` wont fail you here...

> **Delegate** - Description: Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now **or in the future**, based on a
>   specific set of root elements.